# My first stopword in dataframe of each row is not getting removed

Tags: python

I am working on Natural Language processing. I have data frame with review(Rev) column which contains reviews of film. I am able to remove all the stop words but from each row am unable to remove the first stop word if it exist.

" This is very good story"
 my code removes is or any stop words after that but "this" is not getting removed.
I have done tokenization and then removing stop words where I am getting wrong?

t_df['Rev'] = t_df['Rev'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopWords])

Comment: i suspect the most insideous and pervasive of errors, the off by one error, or "oboe". check if your index starts at 0 or 1.